# Perform substitution on regex results, but only on a given condition

Tags: regex, musicbrainz

First of all, let me please clarify that I know absolutely nothing about regular expressions, but I need to write a "Tagger Script" for MusicBrainz Picard so that it doesn't mess with the way I format certain aspects of my tracks' titles.

Here's what I need to do:
- Find all sub-strings inside parenthesis
- Then, for those matches that meet a given criteria and those matches only, change the parentheses to brackets

For example, consider this string:
DJ Fresh - Louder (Sian Evans) (Flux Pavilion & Doctor P Remix)

It needs to be changed like so:
DJ Fresh - Louder (Sian Evans) [Flux Pavilion & Doctor P Remix]

The condition is that if the string within the parentheses contains the sub-string "dj" or "mix" or "version" or "inch", etc... then the parentheses surrounding it need to be changed to brackets.

So, the question is:
Is it possible to create a single regex expression that can perform this operation?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For whoever answering this question, musicbrainz uses Python regex syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ***there are no nested brackets***, you can use the following regex to search for the text:

```
(?i)\((?=[^()]*(?:dj|mix|version|inch))([^()]+)\)
```

Note that the regex is **case-insensitive**, due to `(?i)` in front - make it *case-sensitive* by removing it.

Check the syntax of your language to see if you can use `r` prefix, e.g. `r'literal_string'`, to specify literal string.

And use the following as replacement:

```
[$1]
```

You can include more keywords by adding keywords to `(?:dj|mix|version|inch)` part, each keyword separated by `|`. If the keyword contains `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `|`, `.`, `+`, `?`, `*`, `^`, `$`, `\`, `{`, `}` you need to escape them (I'm 99% sure the list is exhaustive). An easier way to think about it is: if the keyword only contains space and alphanumeric (but note that the number of spaces is strict), you can add them into the regex without causing side-effect.

---

Dissecting the regex:

- `(?i)`: **Case-insensitive** mode
- `\(`: `(` is special character in regex, need to escape it by prepending `\`.
- `(?=[^()]*(?:dj|mix|version|inch))`: Positive look-ahead `(?=pattern)`:

  - `[^()]*`: I need to check that the text is within bracket, not outside or in some other bracket, so I use a negated character class `[^characters]` to avoid matching `()` and spill outside the current bracket. The assumption I made also comes into play a bit here.
  - `(?:dj|mix|version|inch)`: A list of keywords, in a *non-capturing group* `(?:pattern)`. `|` means alternation.
- `([^()]+)`: The assumption about no nested bracket makes it easier to match all the characters inside the bracket. The text is *captured* for later replacement, since `(pattern)` is capturing group, as opposed to `(?:pattern)`.
- `\)`: `)` is special character in regex, need to escape it by prepending `\`.

Comment: I think it depends on the language, but strictly speaking the replacement should just be `[$1]` as there are no `[]` in replace regexes (i.e. no character classes).

Comment: @dicarlo2: Was editing and realized that. Thanks anyway for pointing that out.

Comment: @xfx: Please read the assumptions and the instruction to add keyword carefully. Note that the solution will not work correctly if the input does not satisfy the assumption.

Comment: @dicarlo2: You are right, I had to remove the escaped brackets for the replacement regex...

Comment: Thank you for the added explanation; I truly appreciated.
And I can confirm that, so far, it is working just perfectly.
Here's the resulting code I ended up using the plugin:
    metadata["title"] = re.sub(r"\((?=[^()]*(?:dj|mix|version|inch|edit|radio))([^()]+)\)", r"[\1]", metadata["title"], flags=re.IGNORECASE)